# How to add Facebook/Google+/Twitter sharing buttons to mobile app (PhoneGap)

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, facebook, cordova, google-plus

I'm developing a mobile application (by `jQuery Mobile` And `PhoneGap`).

How to add `Facebook`, `Twitter` and `Google+` `Sharing buttons` into my application? Is there any API or such easy way? (The server-side of my application uses `ASP.NET MVC 4`.)

It doesn't matter that purposed way is server-side or client-side.

(For example, Zite app has sharing buttons)

**EDIT:** If your purposed method needs opening popup window, will `PhoneGap` handle this popup **and close it after sharing, so user can come back to my application?**

**And How to save user's credintals so user don't want to login every time?** (credientals should be saved on client-side, by cookies or something else... (Do we can allow `PhoneGap` for saving cookies from `Facebook`, `Twitter` and `Google`?))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am currently using [this plugin](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin) for sharing options in Cordova 2.5+.

Its working perfectly for Android and iOS

Comment: It seems to be a good plugin. I will use it on my future projects. I'm marking your answer as accepted answer.

Comment: this doesn't work for google plus. How do I use it for g+ sharing?

Comment: Have you Google Accounts Enabled. Basically this plugin only initiate those sharing options which are available as native sharing options.

Answer (score 9):

What you're asking (after your edit) is pretty involved, but here are some pointers.

For Facebook, you can use the [PhoneGap Facebook Platform Plugin](https://github.com/davejohnson/phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect) or use the [Javascript SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/). You'll need to register your app with them and get an app ID. Since there are quite a few steps to FB auth, study their samples and look for a good [tutorial](http://www.drewdahlman.com/meusLabs/?p=88).

Twitter provides a similar auth API, but it requires some server-side code to get it working. I've never used Google's, but I assume they have a fairly simple API as well. Credentials with all of these API get saved in the PhoneGap `UIWebView`'s cookie store, so you don't really have to manage that.

For popups in PhoneGap, you can use the [ChildBrowser Plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/ChildBrowser).

Here's what I use for the buttons. This is called on the client after your page is done loading. Since they take awhile to load and position themselves, a four second delay is used to give them time, then they fade in.

**Demo:** <sub><sub><sub>[image: jsFiddle]</sub></sub></sub>

#### Script

```js
function showSocialButtons() {

    var html =
              '<div id="social-buttons" class="fade">'
            + '<div class="fb-like" data-href="YOUR_URL" data-send="true" data-layout="box_count" data-width="50" data-show-faces="true" data-colorscheme="dark"></div>'
            + '<div class="g-plusone-frame"><div class="g-plusone" data-size="tall" data-href="YOUR_URL"></div></div>'
            + '<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="YOUR_URL" data-text="YOUR_APP_DESCRIPTION" data-count="vertical">Tweet</a>'
            + '<div id="fb-root"></div>'
            + '</div>';
    document.getElementById( 'viewport' ).insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeEnd', html );

    var script = document.createElement( 'script' );
    script.async = true;
    script.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=YOUR_FB_APP_ID';
    document.getElementById( 'fb-root' ).appendChild( script );

    script = document.createElement( 'script' );
    script.async = true;
    script.src = document.location.protocol + '//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';
    document.getElementById( 'social-buttons' ).appendChild( script );

    script = document.createElement( 'script' );
    script.async = true;
    script.src = document.location.protocol + '//apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
    document.getElementById( 'social-buttons' ).appendChild( script );

    window.setTimeout( function () {

        document.getElementById( 'social-buttons' ).removeAttribute( 'class' );

    }, 4000 ); //4 second delay

};
```

#### CSS

```css
#social-buttons {
    height: 300px;
    transition:             opacity 1000ms ease;
        -moz-transition:    opacity 1000ms ease;
        -ms-transition:     opacity 1000ms ease;
        -o-transition:      opacity 1000ms ease;
        -webkit-transition: opacity 1000ms ease;
    width: 90px;
}

.fb-like,
.g-plusone-frame {
    margin: 10px 0 10px 3px;   
}

.g-plusone-frame {
    display: inline-block;
}

.twitter-share-button {
    margin: 10px 0;
}

.fade {
    opacity: 0 !important;
}
```

#### HTML

```html
<div id="viewport"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but since I'm developing a mobile app, It is not good to open popup windows for logging in...

Comment: @Mahdi I use these on a mobile PhoneGap app. Your users are going to have to login to use any social buttons no matter how you do it. In my app they are already logged into Facebook.

Comment: Can you explain more please? How users are already logged into Facebook in your app?

Comment: @Mahdi I use the Javascript FB API for auth.

Comment: @Mahdi Updated with some more info.

Comment: Do their "+Share, Tweet, Like" buttons work (even with popup for login) or I need to use their API?

Comment: @Mahdi These are those buttons. I took that code and cleaned it up and added it dynamically with Javascript.

Comment: So, Will PhoneGap handle popup windows of these buttons and close it after sharing, so user can come back to my application?

Comment: @Mahdi No. You'll have to determine if they are logged in using the API and then use ChildBrowser to log them in if they are not. I would make that part of your registration process and only show the buttons they choose to link.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14474/discussion-between-mahdi-and-thinkingstiff)

Answer (score 3):

Check out [ShareThis](http://sharethis.com/). It allows you to easily add these buttons to your application.

Comment: It seems that ShareThis has not a mobile API for web-based mobile applications.

Comment: And if I use their javascript code (client side), Will it open popup windows for logging in? (because it is not good for mobile developing!)

Comment: Oops, linked to the wrong API. But for web-based mobile applications, you don't need a special API. You can just use the standard generated buttons. And no, it opens a new tab.

Comment: Isn't there any way to **not** open a new tab? (e.g. opening a virtual popup window using iframe?)

Comment: I'm not sure. I only used it once for a very simple website. But didn't you just say you didn't want popup windows?