# How to do facebook integration in jquery mobile phonegap

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I need to implement facebook integration using jquery mobile.I need to get my friend list , post a wall and like page functionality in my app .I create a **APP ID** .But after that i have to do so that it is fun on android and IOS using jquery mobile?

Answer (score 0):

You can see a sample project on [github](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11639933/how-to-add-facebook-google-twitter-sharing-buttons-to-mobile-app-phonegap?answertab=votes#tab-top) answer might also help.

Comment: We use here phonegap plugin? Is there any plugin in jquery mobile?